# How to make scrollbar go away when element inside go back from overflow state

Tags: css

All:

I wonder how can I make a DIV recalculate the overflow when the elements inside change size, for example:

```js
function changeSize(){
    d3.select("#inner")
        .style({
            width: "195px",
            height: "195px"
        })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 200px; height:200px; background-color: lightblue; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="inner" style="width: 250px; height:250px; background-color: lightpink;">
        this is a inner eleement
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="changeSize()">CHANGE SIZE OF INNER ELEMENT</button>
```

The problem is:

Initially, the `#inner` DIV make the outer container DIV overflow, but after click change size button, it becomes smaller that container DIV, but because the scrollbar of previous overflow take some space(around 17px each), the container still think the inner DIV too large, which should be not. How can I make the outer container re-determine its overflow without consider previous affect?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden` on your `outer` div and set to `auto` again. You can change `1000` to `1` for example.

```
function changeSize() {
  d3.select("#inner").style({
    width: "195px",
    height: "195px"
  });
  d3.select("#outer").style({
    overflow: 'hidden'
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("#outer").style({
      overflow: 'auto'
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/RazpxW)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I wonder why it needs a async operation, I tried similar pattern without setTimeout and put overflow hidden setting before size changing, and it does not work

Comment: Thanks, this works very well other than some extra code and flash( when we set the overflow hidden, the content( say its size still larger than container) behind the scrollbar will flash )

Comment: Hmm possible solution: you can change the value of the `overflow` property from `scroll` to `auto` instead of `hidden` to `auto` only when new size is greater than current, and change from `hidden` to `auto` when new size is smaller than inner box.

Comment: Or easier: change the `overflow` property only when new size values are smaller than inner box.